# The most effective method for implementing real-time list refresh for multiple users

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I'm working on a project, and one of the requirements is that if one user is already editing one of the data in the list, the other user's list will be automatically removed. I've been looking around and decided to give SignalR a shot. Do you think this is feasible?

Repository

```
public async Task<(bool success, string message)> ApprovalForMoveOrder(MoveOrder moveorder)
{
   using (var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
   {
      try
      {
        var existing = await _context.MoveOrders
          .Where(x => x.OrderNo == moveorder.OrderNo)
          .ToListAsync();

        if (existing == null)
          return (false, "Order number not found");
        foreach (var item in existing)
        {
          item.ApprovedDate = DateTime.Now;
          item.ApproveDateTempo = DateTime.Now;
          item.IsApprove = true;
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        transaction.Commit();
        await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("RefreshOrderList", existing);
        return (true, "Order approved successfully");
      }
      catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
      {
        transaction.Rollback();
        return (false, "Item is locked by another user");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("ApproveListOfMoveOrder")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ApproveListOfMoveOrder([FromBody] MoveOrder moveorder)
{
  (bool success, string messages) = await _unitOfWork.Order.ApprovalForMoveOrder(moveorder);

  if (!success)
    return BadRequest(new { messages });
        
  await _unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();

  return new JsonResult(new {messages});
}
```

Your comments and suggestions are much aprreciated

I've already try SignalR and open for suggestions for better approach

Comment: This is probably gonna get closed unless you ask a more specific question, but SignalR is a great option for this yes. It can present some challenges in production (esp with load balancers) but nothing that hasn't been dealt with by lots of people already.